# PHP : file_get_contents shows PHP code

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents("file.php");
?>
```

And in my file.php file, I have the following code:

```
<?php
include_once("../includes/connect.php");
$query = $db->prepare("select * from messages");
$query -> execute();
?>
```

when I run the code.. I got the following output:

```
prepare("select * from messages"); $query -> execute(); ?>
```

I tested this on other files also. The mysqli queries in the page were showing were not being performed. I want it to do the opposite. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `file_get_contents()` doesn't execute what it loads. it's just sucking bytes from disk into a string in memory. if you want to execute a file from disk, you include/require it. Doesn't matter if that file is php code or not. if you f_g_c() it, it's just plaintext as far as PHP is concerned

Comment: but the problem is if anyone else does the same way they will be able to see my php code.. will they?

Comment: what "anyone else"? people using your site? other people using your server for their own sites?

Comment: If you look at the HTML source of that output, you'll probably see the rest of that file. Your browser is interpreting the opening PHP tag and the object arrow as one opening tag, and not displaying it.

Comment: @MarcB I can use this function on google with file_get_contents("http://www.google.com").. the same  way if anyone uses this on my file... will they be able to see my php code?

Comment: you are NOT understanding how PHP works. if someone on some OTHER server does `file_get_contents('http://example.com/file.php')`, they're going to be EXECUTING that php code and downloading its OUTPUT. Unless your server is totally misconfigured, it is NOT possible to download the raw PHP code, unless you provide them with the url to your `f_g_c()` script.

Comment: @MarcB So, Why does it happen with my own server?

Comment: because `file_get_contents('file.php')` and `file_get_contents('http://yoursite.com/file.php')` are two completely separate actions. the plainfile is a purely local filesystem operation. no different than fopen/fread/fclose. The url version invokes the http layer, and is no different than typing that url into a browser. a full HTTP request is done, and the webserver EXECUTES the php code, as it's supposed to.

Comment: when you f_g_c() on a url, YOUR server is not executing the code. The server handling that url is, and you download the output of that execution.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, `echo file_get_contents("file.php");` is what are you doing wrong.

any reason you aren't using the same `include` you already used in the other file?

Answer (score 0):

This is a BASIC concept in php.  What you are looking for is `include()` or `require()`

Comment: what if someone else uses this function with my file.. They can see my php code or not?  Thats my worry.

Comment: They can only see your code with `file_get_contents` if they're inside your server/domain.